# ActionBar with NoTitleBar Theme.Holo.Light

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I have an Android tabbed app. I don't want anything else other than the tabs to be displayed at the top of the screen.

This works alright, the only problem is that, when launching the app, for a short moment < 1sec, I can see the title bar with the application launcher icon.

Why is this happening, is there a way to prevent this?

styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBarStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/NoTitleText</item>
        <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/NoTitleText</item>
        <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NoTitleText">
            <item name="android:textSize">0sp</item>
            <item name="android:textColor">#00000000</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.nfcproducttracing.ProductTracer"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
```

This makes my tab text white and barely visible.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent this you must use styles defined in xml file insted of seting everything in your onCreate method.

Before this line in code is execued
`actionBar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);`
your application is already visible.

Try this:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    </style>


    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBarStyle</item>
    </style>

<style name="CustomActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/NoTitleText</item>
        <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/NoTitleText</item>
        <item name="icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="NoTitleText">
        <item name="textSize">0sp</item>
        <item name="textColor">#00000000</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Comment: How do I use this? Thank you.

Comment: I use the Theme.Holo.Light and wish to have an actionBar for the tabs but no title. is this possible? I have set `<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>` under my styles.xml but the title bar is still visible. Please check my edited answer.

Comment: Please check my new edit, this makes my tab text white on an almost white background.