# getActionBar returns null - how to have NoTitleBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme

So I have this under my Activity's onCreateView()

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
```

And my manifest looks like this

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.nfcproducttracing.ProductTracer"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
```

What I have achieved is have my application with Tabs, but no TitleBar. However, during application launch I can briefly see the TitleBar before it disappears, and I do not want that.

What am I supposed to do? When I set my activity theme to anything related to NoTitle, getActionBar returns null and the app crashes.

Comment: How is this question different from [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20612231/741249)?

Comment: I tried to implement the answer from my previous question and encountered the problem I am describing here. `getActionBar()` returns null.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask the original answerer for clarifications. And perhaps [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6867076/741249) will help?

Comment: I am trying to solve a problem and I get -1'd instead. Nice.

Comment: @hermann, have you tried `getActionBar().setTitle("");`? As I answered below?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your questions, you can use the requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE) from your activity.

Flag for the "no title" feature, turning off the title at the top of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure but have you tried this:

```
getActionBar().setTitle("");
```

It will set a blank title for your `ActionBar`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `getSupportActionBar()` instead.
this is from `android.support.v4.app.actionbar`, not from `android.app.actionbar`!